# Android: restore/saving view in ViewPager (no fragment!)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I made a simple view with restore / saving methods with some fields like that:

```
public class FoodMainStepView extends WizardBaseStepView {

    private EditText mNameEditText;
    private EditText mCategoryEditText;
    ...

    public FoodMainStepView(Context context) {
        super(context);      
    }

    public FoodMainStepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FoodMainStepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        ...

        mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.mNameEditTextSaved = mNameEditText.getValue();
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if(!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }

        SavedState ss = (SavedState)state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

        mNameEditText.setValue(ss.mNameEditTextSaved);
    }

    private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        public String mNameEditTextSaved;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            mNameEditTextSaved = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeString(mNameEditTextSaved);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
                    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SavedState(in);
                    }
                    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }
}
```

The base class is:

```
public abstract class WizardBaseStepView extends FrameLayout {

    @BindView(R.id.container)
    FrameLayout mContentView;

    public WizardBaseStepView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public WizardBaseStepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        treatAttibutes(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public WizardBaseStepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        treatAttibutes(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    protected void treatAttibutes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.WizardBaseStepView);
//        final int N = a.getIndexCount();
//        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
//            int attr = a.getIndex(i);
//            switch (attr) {
//                case R.styleable.WizardBaseStepView_title:
//                    mTitleStep = a.getString(attr);
//                    break;
//
//                case R.styleable.WizardBaseStepView_editorTitle:
//                    mEditorTitle = a.getString(attr);
//                    break;
//            }
//        }
//        a.recycle();
    }

    protected void init() {
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.wizard_base_step_view, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        inflate(getContext(), getContentLayoutResource(), mContentView);

        setSaveEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

All fields are an ID.

I use this view into a pager adapter (with viewpager). It's a standard implementation.

The methods restore and saving are called correctly; BUT my `mNameEditText` is always unfill; I can't understand why because on restore instance method the value given is correct (I verified it with debugger): `mNameEditText.setValue(ss.mNameEditTextSaved);`

Could you help me guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's because PagerAdapters are stupid out of the box, so you need to save, store and restore hierarchy state manually.

Comment: Ok, but have you  got an example please ?

Comment: well I had this thing [FlowlessPagerAdapter](https://github.com/Zhuinden/flowless/blob/master/flowless-viewpager-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/flowless_viewpager_example/FlowlessPagerAdapter.java)

Comment: I use this custom viewpager: https://github.com/newfivefour/BlogPosts/blob/master/android-viewpager-saving-state-without-fragments.md